# Node GraphicsMagick: `geometry does not contain image (unable to crop image)`

Tags: node.js, imagemagick, graphicsmagick

I'm resizing an image using Graphics Magick and then using a loop to do multiple crops on that image. The second time the crop command runs, it fails with: `Command failed: gm convert: geometry does not contain image (unable to crop image).`

Here's my loop code:

```
  var resizedImage = gm(pathToTemporaryImage).resize(maxSize, maxSize);

  resizedImage.size(function(error, size) {
    for (var x = 0; x < size.width; x += kGridSize) {
      for (var y = 0; y < size.height; y += kGridSize) {

        // Calculate the grid element width and height
        var width = Math.min(kGridSize, size.width - x);
        var height = Math.min(kGridSize, size.height - y);

        resizedImage.page(0, 0, '+0+0')
                    .crop(width, height, x, y)
                    .quality(Math.min(frameTick.quality, 100))
                    .write(pathToImage + '-' + x + '-' + y + '.jpg', callback(x, y));
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of caching `resizedImage`, I wrote the image to disk after resizing and loaded it back up before cropping and re-writing.

Removed the reference to `.page(0, 0, '+0+0')`, that being the case.